# Prometheus metrics_path gets encoded

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

URL:localhost:15672/api/queues?columns=name,messages

Result: localhost:15672/api/queues%3Fcolumns=name,messages

Prometheus the '?' gets encoded to '%3F' and therefore the request fails

Can you write the result?

```
    static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:15672']
metrics_path: '/api/queues?columns=name,messages'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `params` configuration of the [scrape config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config).

```
# Optional HTTP URL parameters.
params:
  [ <string>: [<string>, ...] ]
```

In your case:

```
static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost:15672']
  metrics_path: '/api/queues'
  params:
     columns:'name,messages'
```

Comment: How do I relabel config this?

Comment: Using `target_label: __param_target`. See examples in the [multi-target exporter pattern](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/multi-target-exporter/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work better for you:

```yaml
- job_name: samplejob
  metrics_path: /api/queues
  params:
    columns: [name,messages]
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:15672
```

Documentation and examples can be found here: https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/multi-target-exporter/#querying-multi-target-exporters-with-prometheus